# How to overlay white text on a white background in WPF so that it is viewable

Tags: wpf, image, overlay

My WPF VS 2008 application is working with many different images that are assembled and displayed at runtime.  I would like to display some white text on top of those images.  My problem is that some images contain a white or light color background.

My question is - is it possible to somehow specify a property or specify a setting in the image object, BitmapImage object (where the image is loaded from), or some other WPF object such that when white pixels from one image overlap white pixels from the other image - they turn a different color so the text will be viewable?

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on how you 'draw' your text on the images. If you use e.g. a Label, you can try out the 'DropShadowEffect', see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748273.aspx

This effect should work with all WPF objects and you can try out some transparent black soft shadows surrounding the text (a little bit like a glow).

This will only be visible in bright environments if you adjust the opacity right.

Answer (score 0):

Decided to use a dark background color for the text that is only partially (.35) opaque.  This means that the background color of the image comes through for the most part, but for lighter colors it yields enough contrast so that the text is viewable.